# how can i implement this code on laravel blade?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

how can i implement this code on laravel blade ?

```
<td>
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $item['image'] ).'"/>';
</td>
```

or is there another solution to display blob image using laravel ?

```
            @foreach($data as $item)
                <td>{{$item->idabsensi}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->idkaryawan}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->masuk}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->pulang}}</td>
                <td>
                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( {{$item->gambarmasuk}} ).'"/>';
                ‌​</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need single quote

```
<td>
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{base64_encode($item['image'])}}"/>';
</td>
```